# How to use Await/Task for DownloadFileAsync/UploadFileAsync or an alternate way to wait till each sub is finished executing

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await, webclient

I am trying to download and upload a file from a url. However, if I use them both together as shown below, since they are async functions, upload starts before download and the bytes uploaded shows as zero.

tmp is a string containing the location for the file to be saved and uri contains the local server address

```
Dim wc1 As New WebClient
wc1.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0)")
wc1.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("file://192.XXX.X.X/volume(sda)/10mb.test"), tmp)

Dim wc2 As New WebClient
wc2.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0)")
wc2.UseDefaultCredentials = True
wc2.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("admin", "admin")
wc2.UploadFileAsync(New Uri("file://192.XXX.X.X/volume(sda)/10mb.test"), tmp)
```

However, if I use DownloadFile/UploadFile instead of DownloadFileAsync/UploadFileAsync, it works fine. However, the below mentioned functions are not executed.

```
AddHandler wc1.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf wc1_DownloadProgressChanged
AddHandler wc1.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf wc1_DownloadFileCompleted
AddHandler wc2.UploadProgressChanged, AddressOf wc2_UploadProgressChanged
AddHandler wc2.UploadFileCompleted, AddressOf wc2_UploadFileCompleted
```

The case is the same for async function, if I use a while loop to check if the webclient is busy or not. The async function does not call any ProgressChanged/Completed functions.

Also, I am not sure how to use and if an await/task function works as required with the async still be able to access ProgressChanged/Completed functions along with waiting for the download to finish before starting the async upload function.

Comment: should you UploadFileAsync first, when it is complete, then DownloadFileAsync ?

Comment: Tried that. Then download completes first and shows the bytes downloaded as zero. Upload starts later and works fine.

Answer (score 3):

`DownloadFileAsync`/`UploadFileAsync` actually *predate* the `async`/`await` keywords, and as such are not compatible with them.

When `async`/`await` hit the scene, `WebClient` got some *new* methods that are `await`-compatible; these are called `DownloadFileTaskAsync`/`UploadFileTaskAsync`. However, I'm not sure if they will raise the progress events or not.

Also, you might want to consider using `HttpClient`, which was designed from the ground up to be `await`-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Does your code actually look like this?

```
Dim wc1 As New WebClient
AddHandler wc1.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf wc1_DownloadProgressChanged
AddHandler wc1.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf wc1_DownloadFileCompleted

wc1.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0)")
wc1.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("file://192.XXX.X.X/volume(sda)/10mb.test"), tmp)    

Dim wc2 As New WebClient
AddHandler wc2.UploadProgressChanged, AddressOf wc2_UploadProgressChanged
AddHandler wc2.UploadFileCompleted, AddressOf wc2_UploadFileCompleted

wc2.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0)")
wc2.UseDefaultCredentials = True
wc2.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("admin", "admin")
wc2.UploadFileAsync(New Uri("file://192.XXX.X.X/volume(sda)/10mb.test"), tmp)
```

You need the AddHandlers after you instantiate the WebClient and before you put it to work for the event handlers to be fired.

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't be using `wc2.UseDefaultCredentials = True` with `wc2.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(...)` - pick one or the other.

Comment: You could probably simplify this a bunch with a single WebClient declared as `Private WithEvents wc as New WebClient` at the top of your class/form/module and use it for all operations, which lets the IDE generate your event handlers for you and wire them up automatically so you don't need the `AddHandler` lines at all.

Comment: I have actually tried with the AddHandlers being added before the events were fired and without them (`Private Sub wc_DownloadFileCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs) Handles wc.DownloadFileCompleted`). But the same issue. Upload starts before download and the bytes uploaded shows as zero. Sorry, if I didn't make it clear.

Comment: When tried with a single WebClient, I get this error message "_An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.dll. WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations_"

Comment: You do realize the Aync method calls don't block, right? The code as I've posted would run straight through, so the timing of event firing will be out of order. This would also be why you get that exception. With one WC, you have to give it one job at a time. In this case, when DownloadFileCompleted fires, give it the Upload job.

Comment: The issues is now resolved. I put the UploadFileAsync function under `wc.DownloadFileCompleted` and now the download finishes and then upload starts. Thanks.